# Finding the equation of a parabola - where is the right triangle for the distance formula here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

So I was watching a [video on Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/intro-to-conics-alg2/focus-and-directrix-of-a-parabola-alg2/v/equation-for-parabola-from-focus-and-directrix) that explains how to find the equation of a parabola, given we have a focus and a directrix.

He draws a picture like this, the focus is at $(a, b)$ and we pick a random point on the parabola at $(x, y)$, the directrix is at $y = k$

The instructor indicates that we want to use the distance formula to help us with that.

[image]

What I don't understand, how can we apply the distance formula here? Where is the right triangle in that picture he drew?

Comment: The two line segment shall have equal length. And to compute length you need the said formula

Comment: @user122049 ok, so the pink line segment and the thicker, blue line segment have the same length, ok I understand that. But I don't get on which line segments he applies the formula.

Comment: He applies them to those segments! Blue - distance between the points with coordinates $(x,y)$ and $(x,k)$. Pink - distance between the points with coordinates $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$. This is the definition of a parabola: the set of all points with equal distances between a point and a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to draw a right triangle to use the distance formula.  But if you did draw one, the one being measured has the line segment $(x,y)$ to $(a,b)$ as its hypotenuse.  The right angle would be at $(a,y)$ (Draw a vertical line through $(a,b)$, a horizontal line through $(x,y)$, and mark the intersection).

The expression on the left is the distance from the point $(x,y)$ to $(x,k)$.  There's no right triangle to draw there, because one of its legs would have zero length.

Comment: Oh, I got it now, thanks for the clarification. The second paragraph is still a bit unclear, if one leg has 0 length, it's still a triangle?

Comment: @Max When one side length is 0, it’s not a triangle at all!

Comment: Ah I think I need to think a bit more about groking the whole thing here, but you already cleared up a lot of questions I had. Thank you!